# How to embed html in Xcode Project for iOs8

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have been developing an iOS application - a really simple application that is based on HTML and CSS (some of them will be using PHP and my SQL) However, I have been trying to find the way to embed HTML file in my project but all the tutorials that I had found (so far) would be either for older version or there is something missing in my Xcode (like file's owner button) which doesn't make it easy or sometimes in the tutorial that I followed had something different from my current version of Xcode. (I am really new to Xcode) my Xcode version is 6.1 running on the latest version of OSx Yosemite. I might have missed something that I should know about embedding HTML file in Xcode 6 for iOS8? I would be appreciated for any answer. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot embed PHP in iOS application. It can only display HTML pages (includes CSS and Javascript). To load PHP pages you would need a server.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do the same a month ago, displaying html in iOS8. My html didn't need CSS though. But I suppose the way to do it is not so different.

We can load the html file as string and that display it with an UIWebView as follows:

```
var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("HtmlFileName", ofType: "html")
var htmlString = NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile(filePath!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
var myWebView = UIWebView(frame: DeviceUtil.getScreenRect())
myWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)

var viewController = UIViewController()
viewController.view = myWebView
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: The code is written in Swift so there is no *.h file anymore. For Objective C, you can put the code in the viewController.m from which a new ViewController will be created. Or simply add the myWebView to the view in which you want to display.